# Does elastic search update its index by itself if i am using jdbc river with mysql?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, full-text-search, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch for searching in a mysql database. What happens if there is a new entry in the database. Does elastic search update the index by itself or do i have to do something externally? How do companies using elasticsearch handle realtime data addition to the database? Is the index updated immediately or do they run a update index code at regular intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is a new entry in the database, i.e when you index a new kind of document, elasticsearch constructs a default mapping for the fields that you have in your document.

After indexing the data, you can view the mappings by this query.

```
curl -X GET 'localhost:9200/index_name/type/_mapping?pretty=true'
```

After indexing a new document when you fire the above query, you will see that ES would have created certain default mapping for the fields.

This is what makes real-time addition of data easy in ES. For example, if the value that you pass in your index is an `integer`, then ES would set its default mapping as type `long`. And if it's a certain time format, then it will use type `datetime`.

You can find more details about the mapping over [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html)

Comment: I meant, do i have to index the db manually at regular intervals or will it index by itself? e.g. I have a SQL : SELECT * FROM USERS; and if there is a new user in the db, will the new user be in the index or until i do something to index again, he won't be in the index?

Comment: No, you will have to index it it every time you change the properties of the user. Ideally, before every user save, u need to index the user

Comment: If i try to index again, in the mean time, will the elastic search server keep responding to search queries, or will it go down and just spend resources on indexing?

Comment: It doesn't go down. And you are indexing a single user document, right? Indexing a single document don't take so much time that you have to worry about whether it will be responding to search queries.